# Connect web API(Spring-boot) and user interface (html and CSS)

Tags: spring-boot, rest, user-interface

I have created a micro-service and it is working as a web API which I can able work with postman API to do the CRUD operations. Suppose If I want to do these operations using both postman and a simple user interface with the help of html and css, what should I do? How can I make call of html pages in the coding? The following is the sample coding for the web API.

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/rest/db")
public class DbServiceResource {

    private QuotesRepository quotesRepository;

    public DbServiceResource(QuotesRepository quotesRepository) {
        this.quotesRepository = quotesRepository;
    }

    @GetMapping("/{username}")
    public List<String> getQuotes(@PathVariable("username") final String username) {
        return getQuotesByUserName(username);
    }

    @PostMapping("/add")
    public List<String> add(@RequestBody final Quotes quotes) {

        quotes.getQuotes()
                .stream()
                .map(quote -> new Quote(quotes.getUserName(), quote))
                .forEach(quote -> quotesRepository.save(quote));
        return getQuotesByUserName(quotes.getUserName());
    }


    @PostMapping("/delete/{username}")
    public List<String> delete(@PathVariable("username") final String username) {

        List<Quote> quotes = quotesRepository.findByUserName(username);
        quotesRepository.delete(quotes);

        return getQuotesByUserName(username);
    }
}
```

I appreciate if you could guide me on this.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Ajax for HTML and CSS pages to perform CRUD operations.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

$.ajax({
                url : "/example/get",
                type : "get",
                success : function(data) {
                          console.log(data);
                }

            });
```